# alt tags for <image> tag inside an SVG

Tags: image, svg, alt

I have a requirement where I need to add an alt tag for `<image>` which is placed inside SVG

```
<svg class="svg-graphic" viewBox="148 174 757.33 757.33" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g>
                <clipPath id="frame-mask">
                      <path class="st0" d="M905.33,324.23c0-4.36-3.42-7.48-7.89-7.89c-72.15-3.95-130.16-61.96-134.11-134.11">
                      </path>
                </clipPath>
                </g> 
                <image class="img-clipPath" clip-path="url(#frame-mask)" x="148" y="174" xlink:href="./img/sample6.jpg">
                <title>My image</title>
                </image>
</svg>
```

I tried adding title tag but it shows up on hover of the image. But requirement is to add an alt text similar to the one we add in `<img src="sample.jpg" alt="img description">`

Comment: add a [desc child element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/desc) and make the alt text its text content.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work like an alt tag.(i.e) in case if the image added inside<image> tag is not available it should show the alt text

Comment: No, SVG doesn't really work that way. I.e. it's not an exact copy of HTML.